# How to handle the new accounts copying from live24u.com?

Tags: discussion

In reviewing the "Late Answers" queue tonight I've seen (IMO) low quality answers popping up from two strangely named new accounts:

[angularjs-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8702676/angularjs-examples)

[usa-videos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8503962/usa-videos)

The identical way that the posts are formatted would seem to indicate that it is the same source posting.

The answers are basically copied from live24u.com, even the small amount of comments are copied verbatim.  A link to the article on the live24u.com site is at the bottom of each answer.  They don't really address the question at all, but sure they are about the same general topic.

I've flagged these as low quality, but am starting to wonder if there is anything else that should be done with people posting copy-paste like this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you see plagiarism where the answers are otherwise reasonable answers to the question raise a custom flag, tell the moderator where the copying is coming from. It's always possible there's a voting ring and the questioners are involved too. The mods will investigate and deal with the whole thing.

The [Charcoal group](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) exists to catch spammers. If a user is posting spam or abusive answers with a common factor, Charcoal can take steps to destroy those posts faster.

Don't flag as low quality as that won't provide enough information as to what's going on and the flag may well end up declined or disputed.

Downvoting will help a little to rate limit the answerers. Don't go through the profiles to downvote the answers though, just downvote the posts as you come across them.

Comment: What you described is largely what happened. The posts were [identified](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40295631#40295631) [by Smoke Detector (SD)](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40295660#40295660), as live24u.com is already on SD's blacklist (list of spammer sites). The posts were reported by SD into the [rooms which normally receive its reports for Stack Overflow](//charcoal-se.org/smokey/Chat-Rooms). I expect that multiple people, including myself, raised flags. While probably spam, the posts were certainly plagiarism (custom flag, giving mods the source).

Comment: OP said that the answerers added a link to the site. So, an attribution is given.

Comment: @sagarv that still doesn’t excuse or permit plagiarism

Comment: @SagarV, The links were all "Example", or "Example - Demo" at the end of the post. They did not provide attribution, which would be something like: "The above/following content was copied from [link]". *Just* a link to the source is not sufficient. The point of plagiarism is that you're passing off someone else's work as your own either explicitly, or implicitly. It must be *clear* that the copied content is not your own (e.g. in quote format and a "source" link). [Note: Copying would still have been a copyright violation, as the site does not permit copying, but that's a different issue.]

Comment: @SagarV, If it had been a single answer with only a portion of the answer copied form somewhere and they provided a link, I would have either informed the user to let them correct the attribution issue, or just edited the post to provide proper attribution. However, this was 4 answers in 18 minutes. Each post had the entire content as a copy-and-paste of the linked site. The answers were also only tangentially about each question (i.e. they didn't actually answer the question). Thus, it didn't appear that the intent of the users was to actually provide useful answers to questions.

Comment: @Makyen I didn't saw that post. So, it is hard for me to know whether it is link only or a text is given. Now you stated that it is link only without any text. So it is plagiarism and I agree it should be flagged along with a link to the original site

Comment: @SagarV, It appears I miscommunicated. The answers weren't link only. They did have content, just (almost) all of it was copied from the linked site. However, the issue with plagiarism isn't the relative amount of copied content (although that's a potential copyright issue). It's that there was no real attempt to say "I copied this", or "this part was written by someone else". In other words, passing off someone else's work as your own. The fact that it was done multiple times in relatively rapid succession without being directly related to the question speaks to the answer's motives/intent.

Comment: Charcoal's SmokeDetector handles spam and R/A posts - we don't set out to handle plagiarism. I've edited your answer to make it clear.