# Failed on audit question

Tags: support, review-audits, late-answers

I was reviewing *Late Answers*, and I failed in [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17685041). However, I still didn't get what was wrong with the post - not judging the answer correctness. To me, it appears to be a valid post...

Is it a false positive? If it is, I suggest it to be removed from the audit list. If it is not, please, let me know what I was missing here...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357292/how-to-handle-the-new-accounts-copying-from-live24u-com

Comment: In addition to the fact that this post is (fairly stealthy) spam, even if you *didn't* notice it was spam, it's still not a good post, and would merit action.  It has spelling, grammar, and formatting problems (as in *severe* problems, that text is practically gibberish), for starters.   You'd merit failing that audit even if it *wasn't* spam.

Comment: I think a good review strategy is to start with the assumption that SO users that visit the [tag] know more than you do and that they don't flag just for the heck of it.  So if you see no obvious reason why the flag is valid at first glance then do break out of the myopic view provided by the review page and open the Q+A in another browser tab.  At which point, in this case, you'll instantly know a lot more and can never fail the audit.  Fwiw, I found that meta post by simply googling the linked web site, took about ten seconds.  YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a copy-paste from a site, as Hans Passant's link shows, and while the site is linked in the post, it still is plagiarism (the author is not attributed, and the content is not clearly marked as not own work).

Furthermore, it might be considered spam if the author of the question was affiliated with the site.

Tip: if a question or answer links to a site, follow that link, and determine:

- Is it spam?
- Is it plagiarism?
- Can the information represented in the link be incorporated in the answer (don't plagiarize, attribute and check if a compatible license is present. Short JSFiddle links can sometimes be replaced with snippets and such)
- Can the link be removed without harming the question/answer?

Comment: See [the help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) on citing external sources for how to not plagiarize content when citing an external source.

Comment: And how can a reviewer knows a post is copy/paste from X website? Such review tests must not be there

Comment: @Billal Well, in this instance, the site is linked. Links in questions/answers are always reasons to check twice. If it wasn't, I'd fully agree with you.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ actually, that is exactly why they should be there.  If it wasn't an audit and you hit "Looks Ok" and didn't flag, you would be contributing to the plagiarized content remaining on the site.  So while the feedback could be better to explain why without coming to meta, the audit help underscore the need to make sure you aren't blindly approving content that comes in via review.  It is an almost impossible job to do completely for the reason you mentioned, but doesn't eliminate the need to be aware of the fact

Comment: The point of the answer was to spam live24u.com . They got a little more creative with their spam and started pasting code from the site before attaching the link. Someone reviewing this wouldn't have had the context that this site had been spammed ~50 times by a series of coordinated accounts (as indicated in the Meta post linked above), but those posts were flagged as spam, deleted, and the accounts destroyed. Don't know if it was a great audit in isolation, but it was spam and did deserve a spam flag. That makes it an audit case, and I don't want to invalidate the correct spam flag.

Comment: Now, if only [there was a way you could dispute individual audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790)...